# KDE4 does not finish loading

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, kde

I've installed and configured xorg on arch ([using these instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Installing)) and kdebase. I've added dbus and kdm to daemons. After the login with kdm, but before finishing loading the deskop all stops and i can only move cursor by mouse and nothing happens. [This solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE#KDE4_does_not_finish_loading) on the wiki doesn't work for me (because I don't have Nvidia card?). My graphic card is Intel Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have an intel video chipset as well and never had an issue with this.  I've always just installed xorg-server, xorg-utils, xf86-input-keyboard, xf86-input-synaptics, xf86-video-intel and kde (whole group) and it's worked for me out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You might find some useful debugging information at `~/.xsession-errors`, normally it would be plasma-desktop crashing.

I use a Intel card as well, kde4 has no problems loading.

Answer (score 0):

I don't trust those instructions given the groups that are now allowed on install. Install these for Xorg and restart KDM.

```
xorg-drivers
xorg
xorg-apps
xorg-fonts
```

Also given that you have intel...  you might want to make sure that KMS is loaded early. I'd put it in your grub config as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel#KMS_.28Kernel_Mode_Setting.29). I've had interesting problems before if it wasn't loaded early enough.

If that doesn't work you might try installing all of `kde` (group). in the event that some addon you're not thinking of is missing.

*note: I do not have your chip or have had this exact problem so I can't be sure any of this will work*

Answer (score 0):

I've installed all of KDE and all works fine.